# React.js How to loop through multiple API data arrays and add data to table

Tags: reactjs

Creating a React app using the Star Wars API to display the character data in a table. The characters are being returned and added but when the planets get returned, the URL of the planet gets added not the actual name of the planet. Not sure how to loop through the data again to add the planet name to the character.
Expected result: When making the API request the character data and planet data get added to the table.
Actual result: Character data added to the table, planet data returns as a URL for the planet.

```
   class App extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
         isLoading: true,
         characters: [],
       }
     }

   async componentDidMount() {
     const peopleURL = `https://swapi.dev/api/people/`
     const homeWorldURL = `https://swapi.dev/api/planets/`
     const speciesURL = `https://swapi.dev/api/species/`
     const peopleResponse = await axios.get(peopleURL)
     const speciesResponse = await axios.get(speciesURL)

     for(const character of peopleResponse.data.results) {
       const homeWorldResponse = await axios.get(homeWorldURL)
       character.homeWorldResponse = homeWorldResponse.data.results;
       console.log(homeWorldResponse.data.results)
       this.setState({characters: peopleResponse.data.results})
     }

   }


   render() {
     console.log(this.state)
       return (
         <div className="App">
           <Header />
           <Input />
           <CharacterTable characterData={this.state.characters}/>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }
```

Table Component below

```
   <tbody>
                        {this.props.characterData.map(data => 
                            <tr key={data.name}>
                                <td> {data.name} </td>
                                <td> {data.birth_year} </td>
                                <td> {data.height}cm </td>
                                <td> {data.mass}kg </td>
                                <td> {data.homeworld} </td> 
                                <td> {data.species} </td>
                            </tr>)}
                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your for loop you should use `character.homeworld` to access the planet `URL`. there is a catch though, the link at `character.homeworld` is `http` but it should be `https`, so you have to replace it before making the request.

You could use an array `characters` to store each `character` at for loop to avoid multiple `setState`.

Below a working version for you `componentDidMount` function:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const peopleURL = `https://swapi.dev/api/people/`
  const speciesURL = `https://swapi.dev/api/species/`
  const peopleResponse = await axios.get(peopleURL)
  const speciesResponse = await axios.get(speciesURL)

  const characters = []
  for(const character of peopleResponse.data.results) {
    const homeWorldURL = character.homeworld.replace('http', 'https')
    const homeWorldResponse = await axios.get(homeWorldURL)
    character.homeworld = homeWorldResponse.data.name;
    characters.push(character)
  }
   this.setState({ characters })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the primer on Start Wars. So it appears that you don't really need to call the planet and the species APIs separately. Endpoints for those are inside your characters. So you have to get those URLs out and call them them as you loop through the characters. Here is a fully working [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-wright-mijdz?file=/src/App.js). And am also including the code here:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

const CharacterTable = (props) => (
  <table>
    <tbody>
      {props.characterData.map((data) => (
        <tr key={data.name}>
          <td> {data.name} </td>
          <td> {data.birth_year} </td>
          <td> {data.height}cm </td>
          <td> {data.mass}kg </td>
          <td> {data.homeworld} </td>
          <td> {data.species} </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      characters: []
    };
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    const peopleURL = `https://swapi.dev/api/people/`;
    const peopleResponse = await axios.get(peopleURL);

    for (const character of peopleResponse.data.results) {
      const homeworld_url = character.homeworld.replace("http", "https");
      const species_url =
        character.species.length > 0
          ? character.species[0].replace("http", "https")
          : "";

      const homeWorldResponse = await axios.get(homeworld_url);

      const species_info = species_url
        ? await axios.get(homeworld_url)
        : { data: { name: "Unknown" } };
      character.homeworld = homeWorldResponse.data.name;
      character.species = species_info.data.name;
      console.log(character);
      this.setState({ characters: peopleResponse.data.results });
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CharacterTable characterData={this.state.characters} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```